# Is there a way to dynamically merge cells that contain specific text in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets tracker that uses importrange to populate six columns dynamically.  There are five category headers from the data that I'm importing that I would like to dynamically merge across all six columns instead of just populating the "A" column. Rather than manually merging these five cells before sending a daily update email, I would like to find a way to have these cells automatically merge across based on the unique text string in each.

I am not well versed in google scripts, but some searching around has yielded this bit of code as a start.  It keeps returning an undefined value for the range and I don't understand why that is.  Thank you in advance!

```
function FormatCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of National Region Tracker ");
  var range = s.getDataRange("A2:A");
  var values = range.getValues();
  //something wrong with following line not sure what you want
  for( var row = values.length -1; [row][0]; ) {
    if (values[row][1] == 'Upcoming Meetings') {
      s.getRange(row+0,0,1,6).mergeAcross();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Range Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge())

Comment: A range merge wouldn't work in this case because the location of the headers change based on the data being imported dynamically i.e. "Upcoming Meetings" is not always in cell A3 due to the amount of data in the category before it.

Comment: How are you calling the above function?

Comment: function FormatCells() ? Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: How are you calling the above function? Your missing a bracket after your loop and well I don't really under the condition or your final expression in your loop.

Comment: I don't know it doesn't have a function name as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes I apologize I didn't include that part in my initial copy and paste.  This row should be above all of the above code: function FormatCells() {

Comment: So I would recommend that you edit your question so that we call all understand your question better.

Comment: Please provide fake sample data to simulate your problem, instead of using importdata use `={Sheet1!A:A}` etc so put all your fake data in Sheet1 use Sheet2 to simulate your importdata using the `={ }` array formula then in Sheet3 put how you want the output to look and in Sheet4 put your current output you are getting with your formula. Post the sheet link here and then we can take a look and solve the problem possibly without even a script.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that there is no trigger that's going to call a function when you import data.  The only triggers available require a user action to initiate a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
function FormatCells() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Copy of National Region Tracker");
  var r=s.getRange(2,1,s.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var values=r.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    if (values[i][0]=='Upcoming Meetings') {
      s.getRange(i+2,1,1,6).mergeAcross();
    }
  }
}
```